# find positions of substring in a string in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to find the position for a column which looks like this

```
              Length                                                ID
+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXX++++++++++++++XXXXXXXX                 1 
XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX                 2
++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                 3
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                 4
+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                 5
+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXX++++++++++++++XXXXXXXX                 6
XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX                 7
++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                 8
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                 9
+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                 10
```

and I want to find the IDs that their length is all X from position 15 to 25.

I tried to use `len(length)` in python and SQL code:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID,
    CHARINDEX('X','length',15),
    CHARINDEX('X','length',25)
```

and the running time is really long.

But both did not work very well.

I wonder if there is any easier way to do it more efficiently in pyspark or SQL.

Thank you

Comment: a bit confused. what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way. Might be an English problem and cannot understand fully.

**1.** The number of `X` is between 15 to 25.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.withColumn('len', f.size(f.split('Length', 'X')) - 1)
df2.show(10, False)

+----------------------------------------------------+----+---+
|Length                                              |ID  |len|
+----------------------------------------------------+----+---+
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXX++++++++++++++XXXXXXXX|1.0 |13 |
|XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX|2.0 |25 |
|++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|3.0 |34 |
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|4.0 |32 |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|5.0 |27 |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXX++++++++++++++XXXXXXXX|6.0 |13 |
|XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX|7.0 |25 |
|++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|8.0 |34 |
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|9.0 |32 |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|10.0|27 |
+----------------------------------------------------+----+---+

df2.filter('len BETWEEN 15 AND 25').show(10, False)

+----------------------------------------------------+---+---+
|Length                                              |ID |len|
+----------------------------------------------------+---+---+
|XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX|2.0|25 |
|XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX|7.0|25 |
+----------------------------------------------------+---+---+
```

**2.** The position 15 to 25 of `Length` is all `X`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.withColumn('len', f.substring('Length', 15, 10))
df2.show(10, False)

+----------------------------------------------------+----+----------+
|Length                                              |ID  |len       |
+----------------------------------------------------+----+----------+
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXX++++++++++++++XXXXXXXX|1.0 |++++++++++|
|XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX|2.0 |++++XXXXXX|
|++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|3.0 |++++XXXXXX|
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|4.0 |++++++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|5.0 |++++++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXX++++++++++++++XXXXXXXX|6.0 |++++++++++|
|XXXXXX++++++++++++XXXXXX+++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXX|7.0 |++++XXXXXX|
|++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|8.0 |++++XXXXXX|
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|9.0 |++++++++++|
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|10.0|++++++++++|
+----------------------------------------------------+----+----------+

df2.filter("len = 'XXXXXXXXXX'").show(10, False)

+------+---+---+
|Length|ID |len|
+------+---+---+
+------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you so much! the second method is exactly what I want!